# How secure is a serial/terminal/console server, from the serial side?

Tags: vulnerability, terminal, serial

I'm upgrading my home lab, and one of the things I'm planning on introducing this time is out-of-band management through a Raspberry Pi console server similar to this: https://www.packet6.com/configuring-your-raspberry-pi-as-a-console-server/

I've read a lot about the vulnerability of console servers in ICS environments where they can provide a path from internet to real-world devices. What I'm interested in is the other way around. Assuming a box in my management band is connected to an infected host in my DMZ, what if anything can that host do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realistically?  They can (possibly) DoS the OOB management link, and *possibly* the whole OOB management system, and that's probably about it.  However, you have the exact same issue for *any* console connection to a compromised system.

This assumes you're just using the serial link as a serial console (so no SLIP, PPP, or X.25 over it, all of which would potentially open you up to regular networking vulnerabilities), and that all your hardware is good and doesn't have bugs (if you've got questionable hardware, then you may be talking about destroying hardware if the attacker gets sufficiently low-level access to the infected system).